# GA Event Tracking Not Saving Events

Tags: google-analytics

I am using the event tracking in GA (JS code) to track 2 buttons on my site.

I can see the clicks coming through in real time, but when I click on `behavior > Events`, I do not see anything (no events at all).

I have tried to filter and it doesn't work.

What is the common cause for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Most offices/practices do exclude themselves from being reported in Google Analytics. Check if you're IP is not filtered out and if so, check if there is an unfiltered view of your data (in best practice they’re called “Raw”). I agree totally with Frank that the processing from GA to reports can take up to several days.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is likely that the RealTime reports you see in GA are realtime, while the other reports take a while to generate.  Much of what you can see in the realtime interface does not make it to actual reporting but for a few hours, or even a few days.

If you can see them in realtime, then your code is configured properly and you just need to wait a bit.  If you need realtime alalytics which reporting is also realtime look into MixPanel, KissMetrics, Guag.es, or Woopra.